# My view don´t display my tabledata in mvc

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Have a small problem, probably an easy solution but cant figure it out!

I have problem to display my data in my view. I have 5 checkboxes that i want to display all data that belongs to each checkbox. The checkbox work when i hardcode my data in a list in my view, but it doesent work when i want to display the data from my table, what are i am missing?

My code

My model (created from my table with entity framework)

```
 public partial class Full
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Channel { get; set; }
    public string Program { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }
}
```

My view

```
@model IEnumerable<Uppgift4.Models.Full>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "channel_Index";
    var list = Model.ToList();
    var list1 = list.Where(_ => _.Channel == "SVT1").Select(_ => 
    _.Program).ToList();//select records which in one channel
    var list2 = list.Where(_ => _.Channel == "SVT2").Select(_ => 
    _.Program).ToList();
    var list3 = list.Where(_ => _.Channel == "TV3").Select(_ => 
   _.Program).ToList();
    var list4 = list.Where(_ => _.Channel == "TV4").Select(_ => 
   _.Program).ToList();
    var list5 = list.Where(_ => _.Channel == "Kanal5").Select(_ => 
   _.Program).ToList();

 }
<style>
.hiddenRow {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.in-line {
    display: inline;
}
</style>
<br />
<table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Channel
        </th>
        <th>

        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="accordion-toggle">
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="div   
       [id*='demo1']" /> SVT1</td>
    </tr>
    @for (var i = 0; i < @list1.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr><td colspan="2" class="hiddenRow"><div id="demo1+'@i'+" 
        class="accordian-body collapse">Program:@list1[i]</div> </td> </tr>

    }
 <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="div
        [id*='demo2']" /> SVT2</td>
    </tr>
    @for (var i = 0; i < @list2.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr><td colspan="2" class="hiddenRow"><div id="demo2+'@i'+" 
        class="accordian-body collapse">Program:@list2[i]</div> </td> </tr>

    }

    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="div
        [id*='demo3']" /> TV3</td>
    </tr>
    @for (var i = 0; i < @list3.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr><td colspan="2" class="hiddenRow"><div id="demo3+'@i'+" 
        class="accordian-body collapse">Program:@list3[i]</div> </td> </tr>

    }

    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo4" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="div
        [id*='demo4']" /> TV4</td>
    </tr>
    @for (var i = 0; i < @list4.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr><td colspan="2" class="hiddenRow"><div id="demo4+'@i'+" 
        class="accordian-body collapse">Program:@list4[i]</div> </td> </tr>

    }

    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo5" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="div
        [id*='demo5']" /> Kanal5</td>
    </tr>
    @for (var i = 0; i < @list5.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr><td colspan="2" class="hiddenRow"><div id="demo5+'@i'+" 
        class="accordian-body collapse">Program:@list5[i]</div> </td> </tr>

    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

My controller

```
public class FavoritChannelsController : Controller
{
    TvProgramDBEntities db = new TvProgramDBEntities();
    Full f = new Full();

    public ActionResult channel_index()
    {
        List<Full> model = new List<Full>();
        {
            model.Add(new Full { Channel = "SVT1", Program = "fame" });
            model.Add(new Full { Channel = "SVT1", Program = "sport" });
            model.Add(new Full { Channel = "SVT2", Program = "news" });
            model.Add(new Full { Channel = "TV3", Program = "hockey" });
            return View(model);

        }
    }
```

so this actionresult work when i harcode my list, and now when i run the program and push the checkbox SVT1 i get two programs Fame and sport.

But i want to present all the data i have in my table, so i try this:

```
 public ActionResult channel_index()
    {
        List<Full> model = new List<Full>();
        foreach (var item in db.Full)
        {
            f.Channel = item.Channel;
            f.Program = item.Program;
            model.Add(f);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

but i dont get any data in my view when i run the program..

Anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is if you write `b.Full` you will get `IQueryable<Full>` but if you want to do the query you should write `.toList()`.

**Updated:**

In the db you have `Program` with a lot of whitespace, this mean that `"SVT1" != "SVT1    "`. You need to use `Regex.Replace(text, @"s", "")`

You can see some another examples how to remove whitespacehttp://www.csharp411.com/remove-whitespace-from-c-strings/

```
public ActionResult channel_index()
        {
            List<Full> model = new List<Full>();
            //you need to do the query with ToList
            var list = db.Full.ToList();

            foreach (var item in list )
            {
                var initedF = new Full({
                   Channel = Regex.Replace(item.Channel, @"s", ""), 
                   Program = Regex.Replace(item.Program, @"s", "")
                });
                //f.Channel = item.Channel;
                //f.Program = item.Program;
                model.Add(initedF);
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: @Michael please provide `TvProgramDBEntities` class code

Comment: Not sure what you mean with Entity framework class, is it the table i posted you mean? Tryed your code but cant still get any data in my view  #maksym

Comment: could you please share your code in the `TvProgramDBEntities`  class?

Comment: TvProgramDBEntitities is my databasconnection. My data is stored in table full (class). Cant find any special class code for TVProgramDBEntities, where do i find that in MVC Project? My database have no relationsship to other tables..

Comment: Ok. Then do this before foreach `var list = db.Full;` and send me what will be in the  `list`

Comment: also you can read [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-mvc-application-using-entity-framework-code-first-approach/) and after that all will be work I think

Comment: thx for the link. I will check it out. I havent mention it but i dont have any problem to display my full table in a view when i use html.displayfor (my table get listed in the view)  I just have problem when i try to present this in my checkbox view!

Comment: @Michael if in the first example it works (but there should be an error "no return", you need  `pass return View(model);` after initialization the model), then in the second example you didn't get any data from the db

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Full] (
[Id]       INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Channel]  NCHAR (50) NULL,
[Program]  NCHAR (50) NULL,
[Category] NCHAR (50) NULL,
[Date]     NCHAR (50) NULL,
[Time]     NCHAR (50) NULL,
[Length]   NCHAR (10) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is what i should write in the controll!, it doesent work  Got an error with the () after new Full so i took it away, can it be the problem?

```
 public ActionResult channel_index()
    {
        List<Full> model = new List<Full>();
        //you need to do the query with ToList
        var list = db.Full.ToList();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var initedF = new Full
            {
                Channel = item.Channel,
                Program = item.Program
            };
            //f.Channel = item.Channel;
            //f.Program = item.Program;
            model.Add(initedF);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```